# Trello API authentication

Tags: api, trello

I followed the trello's guide to connect my TEST webapp to my trello board with client.js (https://developers.trello.com/get-started/start-building#connect)
**Everything went well.** and I was able to add cards to my boad.

**I revoked the app from my trello's settings** and tried to connect my PROD webapp but now when I want to create a card (same code), I have this error

> POST https://api.trello.com/1/cards/ 401 ()

In console I can get the Trello.authorize success log, but the popup for authentification never appears again and the app is not listed in my Trello's settings.

Can someone point me to the right direction to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the local token created during the first authentification.